# RaphaelJS/Snap.SVG drag events?

Tags: javascript, raphael

Raphaël (and its successor, Snap) both have a `drag()` method ([Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.drag), [Snap](http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Element.drag)), and both claim:

> Additionally following `drag` events will be triggered: `drag.start.<id>` on start, `drag.end.<id>` on end and `drag.move.<id>` on every move. When element will be dragged over another element `drag.over.<id>` will be fired as well.

The question is, those additional events are triggered *on what*? I've tried a `document.addEventListener('drag.move.0')` and `paper.node.addEventListener('drag.move.0')` and neither seems to be triggered. What object(s) do I need to listen to, to get those global drag events?

Comment: I'm not sure the implementation is that good (interested if you get it working ok) http://jsfiddle.net/Qnjqc/3/ is an example I just did, but I think you will find it not very consistant. I note in Snap, some of that code is commented out, so not sure if its implemented there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, did my own source-diving and found it's a bit tangled, as Ian supposed. Firstly, in Snap, the event names changed to have a `snap.` prefix ([source](https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/blob/master/src/mouse.js#L450-453)).

Looking at that source code, Snap is using its own event library ("Eve"), that doesn't use native listeners at all, so events aren't bound to any object, they're just namespaced for the thing you're interested in knowing about:

```
eve.on('snap.drag.start.0', function(el) {
  console.log('Item 0 started dragging!');
});
```

The parameter passed to the listener is either the `start_scope` passed to the original `drag()` call, or the element being dragged if it wasn't set at that time.

The `eve` library does allow for wildcards in its scope, so something like:

```
eve.on('snap.drag.start.*', function(el) {
  console.log('Item ' + el.id + ' started dragging!');
});
```

Should work to listen to all drag actions.